# Calculating the mean from an exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, average

could someone please tell me how I can prove/confirm the information on this [page](http://simlab.jrc.ec.europa.eu/docs/html/exp.html)? specifically the part about calculating the mean, I have my doubts about the -b.

Many thanks

Comment: Evaluate the integral $\int_b^\infty xf(x)\,dx$ (use integration by parts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there is a bad typo. It should be $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}+b$. The easiest way to see it is that the density function is the usual one, shifted to the *right* by an amount $b$.  That shifts the mean of the "ordinary" exponential to the right by $b$.

We could also integrate. There is no real point, since the geometric argument above is enough. But for completeness, the mean is 
$$\int_b^\infty \lambda x e^{-\lambda (x-b)}dx.$$
To integrate, make the change of variable $u=x-b$. We get
$$\int_0^\infty (u+b)\lambda e^{-\lambda u}du.$$
Break this up into the sum
$$\int_0^\infty u\lambda e^{-\lambda u}du +\int_0^\infty b\lambda e^{-\lambda u}du.$$
The first integral is the familiar mean $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$ of the standard exponential. The second is simply $b$.